# Finding closed form of summation

Tags: algorithm, discrete-mathematics

I'm having hard times solving this problem

> What value is returned by the following function? Express your answer as a
>   function of n. Give the worst-case running time using Big Oh notation.
>
> ```
> function pesky( n)  
> r := 0  
> for i := 1 to n do  
>   for j := 1 to i do  
>     for k := j to i + j do  
>       r := r +1  
> return(r)
> ```

First, I try to represent this function mathematically and simplify it

[image]

To check my solution I've created a method

```
public static int mystery(int n) {
    int r = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            for (int k = j; k <= i + j; k++) {
                r++;
            }
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

And it turns out that I did something wrong. Any help or hint highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An error in internal sum

```
\sum_{k=j}^{i+j} 1 = i+1
```